# Why can't sympy converge on a solution in Python?

Tags: python, sympy, derivative

I have an equation I'm trying to find where the derivative of this equation is equal to 1.

I use sympy's solve and subtract 1 from the equation to solve for 0, but it never converges on a solution which in this case should be x=260.806 for f'(x)=1.

Why can't it find this solution and what can I change without rewriting for something besides sympy? It throws no errors, just tries indefinitely.

```
import sympy as sym
from sympy import symbol, symbols, solve, init_printing, diff, lambdify, exp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x_sym = symbols('x')
init_printing(use_unicode=True)
y_sym_orig = x_sym*exp(0.4*(1-x_sym/550))
y_sym_deriv = diff(y_sym_orig, x_sym, 1)
print('Orig=', y_sym_orig)
print('Deriv=', y_sym_deriv)

y_orig = sym.lambdify(x_sym, y_sym_orig)
y_deriv = sym.lambdify(x_sym, y_sym_deriv)

x_sol=solve(y_sym_deriv-1, x_sym)
print('The derivative has y=1 at: ',x_sol)

plt.figure()
x1 = np.arange(0, 300, .1)
y_graph = y_orig(x1)
y_deriv = y_deriv(x1)
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.grid(True, which='both')
plt.ylim(0,1)
plt.plot(x1, y_graph, 'r', label='Original')
plt.plot(x1, y_deriv, 'b', label='Derivitive')
plt.title('Original and Derivitives')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Get out your debugger and breakpoint your way to an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SymPy strongly prefers rational numbers to floats. Add `from sympy import Rational` and replace `0.4` by `Rational('0.4')` in the formula.

```
y_sym_orig = x_sym*exp(Rational('0.4')*(1-x_sym/550))
y_sym_deriv = diff(y_sym_orig, x_sym, 1)
x_sol = solve(y_sym_deriv-1, x_sym)
print('The derivative has y=1 at: ', x_sol)
```

prints

```
The derivative has y=1 at:  [-1375*LambertW(exp(3/5)) + 1375]
```

Notes:

- `Rational(2, 5)` is another way to represent 2/5 in SymPy. `Rational(0.4)` or `Rational(2/5)` would not help: both versions create a Python float first, whose rational form is not 2/5, but rather 3602879701896397/9007199254740992.
- Printing out the equation before solving it (as you did) is a good idea. Here the formula for the derivative is `-0.00108496341646638*x*exp(-0.000727272727272727*x) + 1.49182469764127*exp(-0.000727272727272727*x)` in the original form and `-x*exp(-x/1375 + 2/5)/1375 + exp(-x/1375 + 2/5)` in the rational form. Solving equations **symbolically** when they are full of **floats** is a tall or impossible task, considering how different the floating point arithmetics is from the rules of symbolic mathematics.
- See [Python numbers vs. SymPy Numbers](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/gotchas.html#python-numbers-vs-sympy-numbers) for more.

Comment: Thanks! This helps immensely. Two questions on your solution. Is there a piece of code to put before this to tell SymPy to always handle them rationally? Also, is there a way to output the numeric value instead of the LambertW simplified form?

Comment: Solved my latter question using N(x_sol[0],6) instead of x_sol when printing. I still have the former question about defaulting to rational so I can plug-and-play equations without having to add Rational every time if you know, but I'll continue to research this too.

Comment: No, there isn't a flag that does that. Once a Python float like 0.4 was created, SymPy sees it for what it is: 3602879701896397 / 9007199254740992 when put in fraction form. It does not try to guess that this number was meant to represent 2/5.

Comment: If you just want a numeric solution, SymPy has [nsolve](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html#sympy.solvers.solvers.nsolve) for that. (And SciPy has more powerful numeric solvers.) It is usually impractical to ask for a symbolic solution and then convert it to a numeric one.